# How can I soundproof a hatch door in the floor?

Tags: sound-proofing

Wooden hatch door, it's about 1.5" thick plywood but quite loud below when people walk over it, despite having carpet on top.

It closes against a metal jam so I was thinking of putting some dense foam on the jam so the door would give a little. It could however be a bit weird for those walking over it however (usually paying guests staying for a few days max).

I was thinking the egg-crate foam is more designed to stop sound hitting the crate side, so whereas that would be good so they don't get noise from us, the main problem is the drumming of this door.

Any easy solution other than replacing the door with something more rigid?

Comment: Is the door warped and/or uneven, so steping on it causes it to bang against the jamb?  Can you take the door off and reset it so that it's flush on all sides?

Comment: I'll check that out. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5" X 2 feet X 3 feet or so?
That's not very thick to support 150+Lb without flexing, which'll give you a drumhead effect regardless of how much foam is used.
Consider putting an angle iron stiffening frame on the underside of the door.
Attached **firmly**, it should eliminate flex, and most of the drumming.

Comment: More like a meter by a meter (3.3' x 3.3'). I think I like the angle iron suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

What about weather stripping around where the door closes against the jamb?  That is if the noise is coming from the door striking the jamb?  The slap some sound proofing on the underside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, don't forget that your hinges may need to be oiled / greased well. If there's any movement of metal on metal while you're stepping on the door, you'll have a pretty strong squeak / thud that can be aggravating to fix.